# c++ for_each() lamda function not correct

Tags: c++

Could anybody tell me why the `for_each()` doesn't work in the code below.

I need it to check if the third element in the tuple if not a `nullptr` and if it is not then add the first and third elements to `list`

However, it seems to be adding all elements to `list`.

```
std::vector<std::tuple<std::string, std::type_index, Value>> arguments;


 std::vector<std::pair<std::string, mv::Value>> class::defaultValues() const
{
    std::vector<std::pair<std::string, Value>> list;
    list.reserve((arguments.size()));

    std::for_each(arguments.begin(), arguments.end(),[&list](std::tuple<std::string, std::type_index, Value> arg)
        {
            if (&std::get<2>(arg) != nullptr)
                list.push_back(make_pair(std::get<0>(arg),std::get<2>(arg)));
        }
    );
    return list;
}
```

Update:

`Value` is a class.

What the default constructor is called for it, It populates a `ptr_` to be a `nullptr`.

```
Value() : ptr_(nullptr)
        {

        }
```

Comment: `&std::get<2>(arg)` - this will never be equal to `nullptr`. It either returns a value, a reference, or a pointer and the address of the returned value (regarding also the reference and the pointer value) can never be null, unless there are some dirty UB hacks involved. Besides, why would you want to compare it to `nullptr`? What is `Value`, exactly?

Comment: Use `std::optional` if a tuple element can be logically empty (`nullopt` in that case)

Answer (score 2):

`&std::get<2>(arg)` returns the **memory address** of the `Value` object itself, not the **value** of the `ptr_` that it holds <sup>1</sup>.  That address will NEVER be null.

<sup>1: unless `Value` overrides `operator&` to return `ptr_`, which should not be done!</sup>

You need to drop the `&` so you are comparing the actual `Value` object.  But that will work in your example only if `Value` has implemented `operator==` to take a `T*` (where `T` is the type of `ptr_`) or a `nullptr_t` as input and compares it to `ptr_`.  Otherwise, your lambda would have to access and compare `ptr_` directly instead.

You should also be passing the lambda's `arg` parameter by reference instead of by value, so that you are acting on the original `tuple` stored in `arguments`, and not on a *copy* of it.

Try this:

```
std::for_each(arguments.begin(), arguments.end(),
    [&list](std::tuple<std::string, std::type_index, Value> &arg)
{
    if (std::get<2>(arg) != nullptr) // or std::get<2>(arg).ptr_, depending on how Value is implemented
        list.push_back(std::make_pair(std::get<0>(arg), std::get<2>(arg)));
}
```

In this situation, I would suggest making `Value` implement `operator!` instead (if it does not already) to return whether its `ptr_` is `nullptr`, then you can do this:

```
std::for_each(arguments.begin(), arguments.end(),
    [&list](std::tuple<std::string, std::type_index, Value> &arg)
{
    if (!!std::get<2>(arg))
        list.push_back(std::make_pair(std::get<0>(arg), std::get<2>(arg)));
}
```

Or, implement `operator bool` to return whether `ptr_` is not `nullptr`, or implement `operator T*` to return `ptr_` instead (where `T` is the type of `ptr_`), then you can do this:

```
std::for_each(arguments.begin(), arguments.end(),
    [&list](std::tuple<std::string, std::type_index, Value> &arg)
{
    if (std::get<2>(arg))
        list.push_back(std::make_pair(std::get<0>(arg), std::get<2>(arg)));
}
```

Comment: If you go with the `operator bool` route, which is probably the best option for the `operator`s mentioned, you might want to make it an `explicit` operator. Then it will work [when your actually want a bool](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/implicit_conversion#Contextual_conversions), but not get in the way items times.

Answer (score 0):

Because `&std::get<2>(arg)` can never be `nullptr`. You are literally getting a pointer (with `&`) to some `Value &` returned from `std::get<2>(arg)`.